# telegraf multiline log message and inputs.tail.multiline input plugin

Tags: logging, telegraf, grok

I need to parse a MySQL slow log message with a Telegraf and then pass it to Prometheus.

an example of such message is:

```
# Time: 2021-04-01T13:26:56.734727Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:     3
# Query_time: 3.001243  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1617283616;
select sleep(3);
```

To design a grok pattern that should handle this multiline
log entry I followed the advice from the Telegraf's documentation
and created pattern via the online grok expression designer:

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
# Time: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\n# User@Host: %{NOTSPACE} @ %{HOSTNAME} %{SPACE}\[\]%{SPACE}Id:%{SPACE}%{INT}\n# Query_time:%{SPACE}%{BASE16FLOAT}%{SPACE}Lock_time: %{BASE16FLOAT}%{SPACE}Rows_sent:%{SPACE}%{BASE10NUM}%{SPACE}Rows_examined: %{BASE10NUM}%{SPACE}\nSET timestamp=%{BASE10NUM:timestamp};\n%{GREEDYDATA:query}
```

However it turned out that Telegraf can not parse the grok
regular expression above as a single line, they designed a so named

```
inputs.tail.multiline
```

feature to handle such situations, please also see the reference below:

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/7309

How should I describe the expression below
in the context of inputs.tail.multiline plugin?

```
###############################################################################
#                            SERVICE INPUT PLUGINS                            #
###############################################################################

# # Parse the new lines appended to a file
 [[inputs.tail]]
   files = ["/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log"]
   from_beginning = true
   watch_method = "inotify"
   max_undelivered_lines = 1000
   character_encoding = "utf-8"
   name_override = "mysql_slow_log"
   data_format = "grok"

   grok_patterns = ["^# Time: %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}$"]

[inputs.tail.multiline]
 pattern = "^%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}"
 match_which_line = "previous"
```

This part of the configuration can parse only the very first line
of the log entry that consists from 5 lines and produces the output:

```
mysql_slow_log,host=c1-master1,path=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log time="2021-04-01T13:26:56.734727Z" 1617345403983043021
```

How should I modify the configuration above to parse all 5 lines from the
MySQL slow log entry?

Thank you.